# TabLayout перекрывает текст в Fragment

Tags: java, android

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как быть с такой проблемой: TabLayout находится ниже Toolbar (AppBar). И текст, размещенный на странице приложения, начинает идти от AppBar, из-за чего некоторые строки не видны (ведь ниже AppBar находится TabLayout)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена путем внесения TabLayout в Toolbar (в коде разметки).